# Windows 2008 login via serial cable

Tags: windows, serial

Does anyone know a way to connect to windows 2008 via serial cable?

I mean that you will be able to login to the server properly (via terminal) and then you will be able to run a CLI application.

I found out that there is a way for EMS mode (Emergency Management Service) to do that (somewhat). However, this seems to be more about fixing boot problems than really access the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but the only method that I'm aware of is a bit of a kludge:

1. In Server Manager, enable the Telnet Server feature.
2. Use Windows Firewall to lock it down so that the server will not accept outside connections on port 23. This is important, because Telnet is not safe to use over any kind of an actual network connection.
3. Use the Telnet Client version of Eli Fulkerson's open-source [Telnet-to-Serial Bridge](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/telnet-serial-bridge.php) ([tsb-client.zip](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/downloads/tsb-release/tsb-client.zip)) to open a telnet session to 127.0.0.1, port 23, and bridge it to your serial port.
4. If desired, you could experiment with setting this up to run as a service using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc).